# workbook.save creates a damaged spreadsheet (checkmarks disappear)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a very simple spreadsheet with check-marks I want to modify with Python. When I use `workbook.save()`, the check-marks disappear for some reason.

This is a simplified version of the script I am using, which still reproduces the issue.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
    
workbook = load_workbook(filename='example.xlsx')
workbook.sheetnames
workbook.active = 0
sheet = workbook.active
sheet
sheet.title
workbook.save(filename="example.xlsx")
```

This is the spreadsheet before running the script.

> [image: Before]

This the spreadsheet after running the script.

> [image: After]

I have openpyxl 3.0.7 and I don't get any error messages. When I try to install an old version of openpyxl, like pip 3.0.5, and I open the spreadsheet, I get this message.

> We found a problem with example.xlsx, we can try to retrieve its content.

I don't know if this information can help.

If you want to open the spreadsheet [here you have](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tq9I8kaUz4ja7daV3ak5Mm914YkZES6z/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113963994406124192645&rtpof=true&sd=true).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.xlsm` files instead of `.xlsx` and you have to write:

```
load_workbook(filename='example.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
```

instead of:

```
load_workbook(filename='example.xlsm')
```